# Algebraic Attack on Mix Mode Modular Arithmetic

Tags: modular-arithmetic, algebraic-attack, idea

I have a toy cipher that comprises of Mix Mode Modular Arithmetic (bit similar to IDEA including, **Addition Modulo $2^{n}$** ,   **Multiplication Modulo $2^{n}$** ,  **Subtraction Modulo $2^{n}$** and **circular shifts**). I want to apply Algebraic Cryptanalysis on my toy cipher. For this purpose, i want to estimate **System of Equations** of my cipher. How to estimate number of equations (quadratic, linear etc) and terms (linear, quadratic etc)? 
Reference to any paper for **Algebraic Cryptanalysis of Mixed Mode Modular Arithmetic based Crypto Algorithms** will also be helpful.

Comment: Can't be answered without specifying the specific structure you use

Comment: Let's say my toy cipher is IDEA.

Comment: Then it is not a toy cipher is it ? :-)